# How to fill entire header with image

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap header and I want to set an image as a background. I did it but the image does not cover the entire width of the header, it reaches a certain point and then it repeats itself like this:
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6mSQ.jpg)
When I apply the css rule no-repeat it just cuts the picture and again it does not fill the entire width of the jumbotron div, how can I do so that the entire image stretches fully to the end of the div, here is my html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <h2>Add a new Animal</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
    Species: <input type="text" id="species" class="form-control">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" >
    Age: <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control">
    Last Fed: <input type="date" id="last-fed" class="form-control">
    Last Shed: <input type="date" id="last-shed" class="form-control">
    Addition Info: <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <button id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="animals"></ul>
    <h3>View Current Animals</h3>
    <button id="btnLoad" class="btn btn-info">Load Animals</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and my css:

```
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: url('./../images/Header.jpg') ;
    height: 300px;

}
```

Comment: with a simple google search you would've found https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('./../images/Header.jpg') ;
    backgound-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    backgroud-position: center center;

}
```

if not, you have to take a look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

add `background-size: cover` and it will always cover the whole header, then maybe add `background-position: center` and if there are cropped parts to maintain aspect ratio it will crop from the sides and center the image.

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('./../images/Header.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 300px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can give you a specific height and width to the relavant container, use relative units like vh, vw as can as possible when dealing with container sizes.

```
.jumbotron{
    max-width: 100vw; 
    max-height: 100vh; /* or you can use 100% to expand it through the available space */
    background: url('./../images/Header.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

pay your attention to background-size , background-repeat , background-position attributes here. you can adjust them with different relevant properties as your preferences.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp  you can make this a resource